# Running website on Tomcat 7.0: Windows 2008 R2

Tags: java, sql-server, eclipse, tomcat

My team and I originally had a server running through Eclipse (Java EE), but wanted to switch it to running on the Tomcat 7.0 service found in Windows 2008 R2. We are completely clueless on what files to put where in the Tomcat folders found in program files. The entire server has gone down and we can't go back to the original setup. Any help is appreciated. All we're asking is where do we put our JSP/ROOT ect folders in the Tomcat program files.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Tomcat 7 as Service on Windows Server 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920051/installing-tomcat-7-as-service-on-windows-server-2008)

Comment: Not quite what we're looking for but thanks. We already have installed Tomcat. Now we need to dump our own server files into Tomcat.

Comment: im not sure about win server 08 but usually the `webapps` directory is inside the tomcat 7 folder. If you cant find it you could always do a directory search for it `dir "webapps" /AD /s`

Comment: I found that directory already. I had gotten it to work once before by dumping the ROOT folder into there, but I can't seem to replicate that result.

Comment: What do the tomcat logs say?

Comment: Alot of exceptions....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62634/discussion-between-ug-and-deewbee).

Answer (score 0):

Copying JSP files are not good idea rather you can package your jsp file into an archive file called WAR file. You can export your project from Eclipse IDE as a WAR file.

After creating the WAR file (.war), you need to find out tomcat installation directory and its called tomcat HOME. Now you just need to copy the WAR file into the following folder:

```
{TOMCAT HOME}/webapps/<project>.war
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll add to the answer.

If you have folders of running applications from before you can put 'em under

```
{TOMCAT HOME}/webapps/
```

war file will un-zip after you start the service.
once the war is un-zipped, you can delete it, but only after you stop the service for the first time after war deployment.